# PHP/Laravel Check a condition in a function only once

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-5, lumen

I have written a custom translation function for Laravel, which first checks a configuration variable to see whether to use Laravel's default `__()` function or my custom `trans()` function.

Here's my function:

```php
function t($key, $replace = [], $locale = null)
{
    $source = Config::get('translate.source');
    if ($source == 'database') {
        return trans($key, $replace, $locale);
    } else {
        return __($key, $replace, $locale);
    }
}
```

However, for speed purposes, I don't want the `if` condition to run reach time I call the `t()` function, but only on the first call.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's just a string comparrison, it'll change the perfomance by next to nothing

Comment: And your question doesn't make sense. If the if statement is never ran then how do you know if you want to call __ or trans?

Comment: If you don't want check the source every time, either store the valid function name in your cache, session etc. or make a class and use the __construct. But no solution will gain you any performance unless you make millions of translations.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a variable in the class and refer to that. So, create a variable databaseSource:

`private $databaseSource = false;`

You then want a method that will change the boolean:

```
function updateSource()
{
    $source = Config::get('translate.source');
    if ($source == 'database') {
        $this->databaseSource = true;
    }

    $this->databaseSource = false;
}
```

You can then use this piece of functionality over and over via accessing the variable instead of getting the source every time you need it.

E.g. `if ($databaseSource) { ... }`